# How to uncheck the checkbox when other checkbox is check for asp.net checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

My Asp.net Checkboxes

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="All" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="ALL" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="otherCheckBox2" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Accepted" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="otherCheckBox3" runat="server" Checked="false"  Text="Contacted" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay"  /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="otherCheckBox4" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Pending" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="otherCheckBox5" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Pre-Authorized" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="otherCheckBox6" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Show Deleted" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="otherCheckBox7" runat="server" Checked="false" Text="Treated" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" />
```

Script i tried

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this.checked)) {
                    $('#<%= All.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
                }
            });
        });
```

I want to iterate asp checkboxes and when any checkbox from 2 t0 7 is checked ,uncheck check with id="All".
I request all stackflow experts please suggest me a answer am waiting for answer for long time.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply eliminate the each altogether:

```
$('#<%= All.ClientID %>').prop('checked', !($('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').not(':checked').length));
```

or if it is a fixed id:

```
$('#All').prop('checked', !($('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').not(':checked').length));
// class example of this same thing replaces the id prefix selector
$('#All').prop('checked', !($('.chkdisplay').not(':checked').length));
```

EDIT extra: I suspect you might want a toggle based on the ALL/group so: You can use this or just ignore it if it does not help you.

```
//if any is checked/changed reset All to reflect
$('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').on('change blur', function () {
    $('#All').prop('checked', !($('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').not(':checked').length));
});
// if All is changed, reflect the All setting (check/uncheck the group)
$('#All').on('change blur', function () {
    $('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
// set initial all state
$('[id^="otherCheckBox"]').eq(0).blur();
```

Fiddle showing that last part in function: http://jsfiddle.net/hZFFr/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks reasonable. A few pointers:

- There's no need to wrap `this.checked` in `$()` the way you're using it
- As you've shown that you're aware, by using `All.ClientID`, the ID of your HTML checkboxes may not be exactly that of your ASP.NET checkboxes. You may consider using `$('.chkdisplay')` or some other method to access the checkboxes of interest.
- The code you've posted will only run on DOMReady. You may also want to run it on any `$('.chkdisplay').change`
- If you're running jQuery 1.6 or later, use `.prop('checked', false)` rather than `.attr`

Comment: can u suggest or post answer please

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you cannot use css class? What do you mean by "does not work" in this context?

Comment: when i tried using .chkdisplay as selector  and tried to debug with firebug in mozilla firefox but my cursor did not get .chkdisplay

Comment: I don't know what you mean about your cursor. `$('.chkdisplay')` will yield all elements with the css class `chkdisplay`.